# What is this JavaScript construct: " = [y for each ...]"

Tags: javascript, brackets

```
myColl.y = [y for each (y in myColl.y) if (y != myThing.getY())];
```

I understand what this is doing, returning all the 'y' items that are not the current one...

But, what is the concept called here with the brackets?
I would like to read up on what this is , syntax, etc.

Comment: Nice question. I didn't know they introduced list/array comprehensions to JS already. Too bad JS 1.7 is still not widely supported.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to use that in a web app designed for mass consumption (i.e., IE)

Comment: @Pointy: Not for a while yet, no -- well, not *client*-side, anyway. (Heck, we still can't count on IE or Safari to get function expressions right.)

Comment: I don't get it. Stefan answer the question correctly and immediately and even included a link, the question's been viewed more than a couple of dozen times, and he has precisely one up-vote (mine). Vote people!

Comment: Also, it seems my eclipse is not recognizing this syntax - maybe the javascript plugin for eclipse neds to be updated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an array comprehension.

Apparently this was introduced in [Javascript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7).

Comment: Reminder to all, this only works in Mozilla engines, this is not supported by ECMAScript (the real JS standard). JavaScript is Mozilla's (original) version of JS to which Mozilla has been adding lots of features that are probably never going to make it into ECMAScript